# Can't find variable name in scope

Tags: swift

I am trying to learn Swift and I have bought a book to help me learn the language.
I can't understand why the following does not work:

```
func sum(_a: Int, _b: Int) -> Int {
return a + b
}
func subtract(_a: Int, _b: Int) -> Int{
return a - b
}
var someFunc: (Int, Int) -> Int
someFunc = sum
print(someFunc(5, 4))
someFunc = subtract
print(someFunc (5, 4))
```

The error I get is Cannot find 'a' (or 'b') in scope.

If I remove the underscores it does give the right answer.
I thought the point of the underscore was that the underscore meant that nothing is assigned to it and the function you want to call that returns a result but you don't care about the returned value.
Can somebody explain in simple language why this does not work.

Comment: You need a space between the underscore and the variable names a and b.

Comment: `_a` or `_b`, you meant `_ a` and `_ b` with space.

Comment: Any feedback on the answers you have received?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a space between _ a, _ b. Like this:

```
func sum(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}
func subtract(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int{
    return a - b
}
var someFunc: (Int, Int) -> Int
someFunc = sum
print(someFunc(5, 4))
someFunc = subtract
print(someFunc (5, 4))
```

You can learn these functions in a Playground. You will see there errors, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The underscore means that the parameter will not have a label when calling then function making it more compact.

Below is 3 different ways to use labels for parameters when creating a function

Function with anonymous (no label) parameters

```
func example1(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    a + b
}

let sum = example1(3, 5)
```

Function with parameters as labels

```
func example2(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    a + b
}

let sum = example2(a: 3, b: 5)
```

Function with different parameter names and labels

```
func example3(first a: Int, second b: Int) -> Int {
    a + b
}

let sum = example3(first: 3, second: 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

When declaring functions in Swift, you can provide names for parameters passed to a function. It is handy to make your functions more readable when using in code. E.g. you can declare it like so:

```swift
func move(from startPoint: Int, to endPoint: Int) -> Int {
   return startPoint + endPoint
}
```

In your function's body you can use variables' names, which is quite understandable for you. And usage of your functions will look like:

```swift
res = move(from: 1, to: 2)
```

I this way it will be more readable for any person who will read or use your code. It will be more clear even for you, when you'll return to this code some time later.

You can also declare the function in the way not to show any variables' names at all. For this you can use "_" as a variable's name. And this is the case from your learning book.

Guys have already answered your question. I just wanted to give you a bit deeper understanding.